# how to insert a new value along with other values from table 1 to table 2 by using triggers

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_status_added 
AFTER INSERT ON user_status
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO all_post_status 
          values(new.status_id,new.friend_id,new.status_time_date, ABC);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now i want to insert value 'abc' as a value in field "user_type" of all_post_status table . how to do this

Answer (score 0):

There is `NEW` in insert triggers - it is the newly inserted record.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: didnt get the answer from there, i have a extra field in table post_status_value i.e. user_type which is not present in old table. Now i want to insert 'restricted' as a value in field user_type along with other values how i do this...

Comment: `INSERT INTO post_status_value SET user_type = 'restricted'` ?